# SAP HANA Vora Insert into table?

Tags: vora

I am trying to do an insert into an existing table, but receive incorrect syntax error:

**Statement:**

```
vc.sql("insert into table HIST_TEMP values (0, 'AAA','2010-06-01', 30.5, 12.0)")
```

**Error:**

> org.apache.spark.sql.SapParserException: Syntax error at or near line 1, column 36
>
> insert into table HIST_TEMP values (0, 'AAA','2010-06-01', 30.5, 12.0)
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.SapSqlParser$.parse(SapSqlParser.scala:176)

**Table:**

```
vc.sql(s"""
CREATE TABLE HIST_TEMP(
        INSTRUMENT_ID INT,
        TRADING_SYMBOL VARCHAR(5),
        TRADE_DATE DATE,
        CLOSE_PRICE DOUBLE,
        SPLIT_FACTOR DOUBLE)           
USING com.sap.spark.vora
OPTIONS (tableName "HIST_TEMP",
                 hosts "$vHost",
                 zkurls "localhost:2181") """)
```

Answer (score 1):

Vora currently only officially supports appending data to an existing table (using the APPEND statement). For details see [SAP HANA Vora Developer Guide](http://help.sap.com/Download/Multimedia/hana_vora/SAP_HANA_Vora_Developer_Guide_en.pdf) -> Chapter "3.5 Appending Data to Existing Tables"

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the insert should be

```
insert into <tablename> (col1, col2, col3...) values('val1', 'val2', 'val3'...);
```

Gopal